# How to make an elegant state transition map in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

If you can come up with a better title, please edit!

What I have are two enums, kinda like this:

```
enum State {
    A = "A",
    B = "B",
    C = "C"
}

enum Event {
    X = "X",
    Y = "Y",
    Z = "Z"
}
```

And I want to declare a map which says "If current state is `S` and event is `E` then the new state is `S1`".

Not every state-event combination will have a new state, sometimes the event does nothing.

So, in pseudo-javascript, I want to write something like:

```
const transitions = {
    State.A: {
        Event.X: State.B,
        Event.Y: State.C
    },
    State.B: {
        Event.X: State.A
        Event.Z: State.C
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to write this in an elegant fashion. Object literals cannot have non-string-literal keys (not even interpolated) and indexer types in Typescript cannot be union types and… I'm stuck. Anything that I can come up which works is a lot more verbose and ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer works nicely, but I noticed there is a small issue with it.

Because you used a generic `string` index in `StateMap`, this means that you lose all type safety about how you access StateMap.

For example:

```
const stateTransitions: StateMap = {
    [State.A]: {
        [Event.B]: State.C
    }
};

const x = stateTransitions.whatever // x is { [index: string]: State }
```

We should be able to know that `whatever` can never exist on a `StateMap`.

Here's one option:

```
type StateMap = Record<State, Record<Event, State>>
```

The downside of the above is that it forces you to write out all combinations of states/events in order to compile. So you would need to write something like:

```
const stateTransitions: StateMap = {
    [State.A]: {
        [Event.X]: State.C,
        [Event.Y]: State.C,
        [Event.Z]: State.C
    },

    [State.B]: {
        [Event.X]: State.C,
        [Event.Y]: State.C,
        [Event.Z]: State.C
    },

    [State.C]: {
        [Event.X]: State.C,
        [Event.Y]: State.C,
        [Event.Z]: State.C
    }
};
```

It depends a little on how you expect to implement the state map. Should it include every state as a top level key? If so then `Record<State, ...>` is a good place to start.

One of your requirements was:

> Not every state-event combination will have a new state, sometimes the event does nothing.

You could cover this explicitly by stating that the event results in the same state. For example, if State A does not transition when Event B occurs then:

```
const stateTransitions: StateMap = {
  [State.A]: {
    [Event.B]: State.A
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

Edit:
Following on from the comments below this answer, if you want to exclude certain states from the state map because they are final states for example, you can do so as follows:

```
type StatesToInclude = Exclude<State, State.C | State.B>

type StateMap = Record<StatesToInclude, Record<Event, State>>

// ...
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that out and found the same thing. In the end I decided to go with `string` on the first level and `Event` in the second, because it allowed me to skip about half of the states (they are final and don't participate in event processing at all).

Comment: That makes sense!

Comment: You could use Exclude to exclude your final states. E.g. `Record<Exclude<State, State.C>, ...>`

Comment: Gets a bit lengthy, but, yeah, not bad.That would actually be handy if additional states suddenly got added. I'll put it in.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, found the answer myself 3 minutes later. :D There are "computed property names". So...

```
type StateMap = {  [index: string]: { [index: string]: State } }

const stateTransitions: StateMap = {
    [State.A]: {
        [Event.B]: State.C
    }
};
```

The square brackets are acceptable and don't really bother readability, I think. Thank you everyone for rubberducking! :)